# Cohomology of toric Calabi-Yau manifolds in $d=4$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $X$ be a toric Calabi-Yau manifold, of complex dimension $d=4$.
What do we know about its cohomology?
In particular, if we know $H^{1,1}(X)$ (say we know its dimension and pick a basis), can we say something about $H^{2,2}(X)$ and $H^{3,3}(X)$?

Clarification: let $\mathbb C^{N+4}$ with coordinates $z_a$, and
$U(1)^N$ action $z_a \to e^{\sqrt{-1} \alpha_i Q^i_a} z_a$
for some matrix of integers $Q$ satisfying $\sum_{a=1}^{N+4} Q^i_a = 0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,N$,
and moment maps
$$ \mu_i = \sum_a Q^i_a |z_a|^2 - r_i : \mathbb C^{N+4} \to \mathbb R$$
for real numbers $r_i$.
Then $X= \mu^{-1}(r) / U(1)^N$.

Comment: $H^{1,1}(X) \cong H^{3,3}(X)$ by Serre duality.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thanks, that's true in greater generality. Does some special relation between $H^{1,1}$ and $H^{2,2} hold in the toric case?

Comment: Can you clarify what a toric Calabi-Yau manifold is?